# Serialize an object when posting data with RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, restsharp

I've recently started using RestSharp to consume a REST service which uses XML.

It makes deserializing objects from XML to a collection of custom objects trivial. But my question is what is the best way to *reserialize* when posting back to the service?

Should I use LINQ-to-XML to reserialize? I tried using the `Serializeable` attribute and a `SerializeToXml` utility function, but when I do so it seems to break the deserializing performed by RestSharp.

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to use attributes to get all of what I need, although my situation is relatively simple. For example, to get it to deserialize nodes with dashes in them, and then to be able to serialize to the same node name I used this:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "short-name")]
[SerializeAs(Name = "short-name")]
public string shortName { get; set; }
```

So, in your example, serialization doesn't respect `[XmlElement("elementName")]`. Instead, you will need to use `[SerializeAs(Name = "elementName")]`.

I found this by trolling through the test code in the RestSharp project.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it's not the same as the Standard XML Serialization.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the source code for RestSharp I found that they actually have a built in wrapper for `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` named `DotNetXmlSerializer`, it's just not used by default.  To use it, just add the following line:

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.RequestFormat = RequestFormat.Xml;
request.XmlSerializer = new DotNetXmlSerializer();
request.AddBody(someObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

On a recent project I used XElement (from the System.Xml.Linq assembly) to manually build up my requests. I only had a handful of properties to deal with though. RestSharp solved the real problem which was deserializing the large XML graph responses from the server.

If your object model is dissimilar to XML schema you will have to create another object model, and map to that, just so it can be serialized automagically, using some library. In that situation you may be better off manually mapping to the schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can RestSharp serialize automagically if a class's name and properties have the same names as their XML elements, or do you mean using .NET serialization via xml attributes and then using XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 1):

RestSharp supports some basic XML serialization, which you can override if needed:

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.RequestFormat = RequestFormat.Xml;
request.XmlSerializer = new SuperXmlSerializer(); // optional override, implements ISerializer
request.AddBody(person); // object serialized to XML using current XML serializer
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the built in XML serialization pay attention to attributes such as [XmlElement("elementname")]? Or would that require using custom serialization?

Comment: It does not. I hate attributes :). You'd have to implement ISerializer and pass it through XmlSerializer for that

Comment: @JohnSheehan-Runscope Re: *"I hate attributes"* Looks like you have changed your mind about this...I see that the current version of RestSharp (105.2.3.0) includes the [DeserializeAs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization) attribute. And in the object browser in Visual Studio, I also see now see a **SerializeAs** attribute which is referenced in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726706/1497596).

Comment: @DavidRR I no longer maintain the project, it's taken care of by others now who are free to add whatever features they like :)