# Using XmlRoot or XmlType with RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization, restsharp

I have been trying to Deserialize an XmlResponse using RestSharp, but have been unable to get the correct xml root to be noticed within RestSharp.

A list of MyObject are returned from the server (in xml format), and clientside I would like to serialize that xml into a List.

Everything correlates between MyObject and MyObjectDto except for the name of the class.

Applying XmlRoot and / or XmlType attributes to the class doesn't seem to help (they are disregarded in the RestSharp deserializer).

Is there any way to do this in RestSharp?  Do I need to build a custom xml deserializer?

Comment: post some sample data and the class that you've tried to deserialize to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in a comment by John Sheehan in another post:

[Serialize an object when posting data with RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753663/how-should-i-serialze-data-in-conjunction-with-restsharp)

XmlRoot decorations don't seem to be supported in RestSharp, but you can create a custom serializer to get the functionality that you need if your models and xml don't precisely match up.

I ended up going a different route altogether and serialized the data using the .NET xml libraries.