# How to specify the XML element name when adding an object to a RestSharp request?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

Using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), I am trying to make a POST request to an XML based API. A part of the XML body of the request is an item that should look like:

`<field fid="42">foobar</field>`

To get this done I've created this simple class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "field")]
public class RecordField
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int fid { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

To embed this bit of data into my request I go:

```
var field = new RecordField(42, "foobar");
requset.AddXmlBody(field);
```

This does add the data into the outgoing request body but unfortunately, using the wrong element name:

`<RecordField fid="42">foobar</RecordField>`

It appears my [`XmlRoot]` attribute is ignored.

How can I make RestSharp use "field" as the element name instead of "RecordField"?

PS - Renaming my class to `field` works but is undesirable as it violates my project's naming conventions.

Comment: Add to the parent class property for RecordField the attribute [XmlElement("field")]

Comment: Thanks but there is no parent class for `RecordField`. It's a standalone class that's added to the request via `AddXmlBody()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753663/serialize-an-object-when-posting-data-with-restsharp

Comment: Thanks @jdweng . `[SerializeAs(Name="field")]` did the trick. Would you like to post this as the answer so I can accept it?